# MongoDB. Find documents which contain value from array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have an array with some values.

How can I find all documents which contain in a specific field value from array?

For example:

```
Array : ["1", "2"]
```

Documents

```
{field : "1"},

{field : "2"},

{field : "3"}
```

I need to find:

```
{field : "1"},

{field : "2"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please try this?

```
db.inventory.find( { field: { $in: [ "1", "2"] } } )
```